# Asking Multiple Questions

Tags: discussion

Today, I noticed a comment on this [question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48264/what-are-the-rules-for-punctuating-a-conversation), coincidentally from a new user, where they were told to read the help and tour pages, and instructed that we are only allowed one question at a time here.

I have never seen this before, nor heard of this practice here. So, I checked the advised pages and didn't see anything. Being a relatively new user myself, and having had several questions posted at the same time (open) I am curious if I have been breaking these rules or not?

Can anyone verify this? As well as please let me know what the reason for this policy is (now sheer personal curiosity).

Comment: I think the idea is one question for each thread. You can definitively open more than one thread, each with one question.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing.  I make a point of trying to welcome every new person with a link to the tour and help center, unless someone else has done it already.  And yeah, it's a SE cultural rule that we only ask one question *per post*.  People are certainly allowed to make multiple question posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have as many questions going at once as you like. Putting several questions into a single question becomes a problem, as in the question you linked to. It defocuses the question and often makes for a bad question that's difficult to answer.